# How to make Firefox open pdfs in viewer but download them when you press the download button

Tags: firefox, pdf

When I click on a pdf file in Firefox, I want it to open inside Firefox. This I can do by going to

preferences > applications > PDF file

and set the action to "Open in Firefox"

So far so good. However, I often then want to download the pdf file after looking at it. This I can do from within Firefox by clicking on the "download" button. The problem is that *every time* I do this it brings up a dialog box:

You have chosen to open foo.pdf
What should Firefox do  with this file?
(two options open or save)
with a "do this automatically from now on").

Now in this context (pressing on the download button from within Firefox) I certainly *always* want to download the file, since that's why I'm pressing the download button. But if I select "do this automatically from now on" then it changes the default behavior whenever I click on any other pdf file. In other words, there are two operations I do within Firefox:

1. Click on a pdf file
2. Click the download button within Firefox while the pdf is open inside Firefox.

Is there anyway to configure firefox so that 1) always opens pdf viewer inside Firefox and 2) always downloads the file?

Comment: Short answer: No. They are mutually exclusive options.

Comment: @DavidPostill is there a longer answer?